# SQL prepared statements update value prevent sql injection

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update, sql-injection

I am making my website secure to SQL Injections, so I am using prepared statements. But do I also need this when updating value? I have a text input where value comes from the current row value. In button click, this is how I save the new value in the text input:

**HTML**:

```
<form method='post' action='xtest.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_id' value='{$row['id']}'> <!-- id without url ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278030/14266656 -->
<td><input type='text' name='note' id='note' value='{$row['note']}'></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='btSubmit' value='Submit'></td>
</form>
```

**PHP** (xtest.php):

```
$action = $_POST['btSubmit'];

if ($action == "Submit") {
    $id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
    $note = $_POST['note'];
    
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET note = '$note' WHERE id = $id";
    
    if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
        
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
        
    }
    $link->close();
}
```

Am I doing this secure, or do I need to change things up?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection) will help

Comment: @Aniox Just wondering, is my current code good? Or should I use this one: https://pastebin.com/XtfX3mYG?

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, and therefore am not qualified to make any professional suggestions, but having some experience with PreparedStatements in other environments - it seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing this secure?

Are you using a parameterized query?

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET note = '$note' WHERE id = $id";
```

No, you are not. You are concatenating variables in the query string.

Consider a malicious user posting the following parameters to your form:

```
note: 'foo'
id:   '0 or 1 = 1'
```

Your query string becomes:

```
UPDATE table SET note = 'foo' WHERE id = 0 OR 1 = 1
```

The `WHERE` condition is always true: all rows in your table are updated to `'foo'`, instead of one single row as you intended to.

Do use prepared statements and parameterized queries. Everytime you find yourself munging variables in the query string, that's a red flag. So:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET note = ? WHERE id = ?;
```

More about this can be read in [this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716).

Comment: Ok, so I tried doing it like this: https://pastebin.com/3rZSy6eE , but I get error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in ...:118 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ... on line 118`. Line 118 is: `$result = $stmt->get_result();`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Andrei: are you sure that you are running mysqli? Maybe you are running PDO?

Comment: I am new to this, so how do I know? I am using phpmyadmin, and this is my database_connect.php: https://pastebin.com/sM5jGMdt